# Is there a simple context-menu add-in that could make-up for the Windows-7 status bar deficiency?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management, context-menu

**Edit**: *I initially asked about free disk space and selected item size.  It has since been pointed out that the selected item size summary is still availiable natively in the details pane.   I had read elsewhere (wikipedia) that this was removed along with disk free space, which is not the case.  Only free disk space has been completely removed.  Selection size is still availiable.*

Is there a context menu add-in out there that could show the free disk space of the relevant drive, when you right click?   This would go a long way to compensating for one of the only steps backward I’ve discovered in Windows 7 so far.   I doubt anyone had created one specifically for this need before Windows 7 because this information was previously easily accessible in the status bar.

I thought about creating one, but it has been a while since I have messed with the Shell API, and I know there are coders out there who could do it faster and better.

If you’ve heard of one, or know of something else to make-up for this Microsoft misstep, I’d appreciate hearing about it.

If MS were listing to the community they would already have a powertoy or add-in of some kind to un-break this. (they could release it unsupported even), as there seem to be many power users that are extremely annoyed by this feature removal decision.  If anyone has seen something, please post it here.

As it has been only 4 days since official Windows 7 release, I'll wait at least a week to chose an answer.

Here's a picture of protoype screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

[SU question 19232](https://superuser.com/questions/19232/is-there-a-way-for-windows-7-to-show-remaining-disk-space-in-the-status-bar) is related.

Comment: yep, this 'Show more details' link in the Details pane is a slap in the users face. what where they thinking? :)

Comment: Er, you know you can turn on the Details Pane in Explorer via 'Organize > Layout > Details Pane'. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Ah, The details pane *does* show total size of selected items.  My bad.  I read other complaints about the missing free space info, which also mentioned missing selection summary, and propagated that bad info without checking facts for myself.    That is still there.  Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: Still, an easily accessible free space indicator would be real handy especially when dealing with removable media.   And there is *no way* to turn that on without a 3rd party ad-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Filemenu tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/index.html) meets the first of your requirements and has plenty of other useful context menu options.

Comment: There is nothing in FileMenu Tools to display the size of selected items nor the free disk space.

Comment: +1 for a pretty cool context menu tool.   But it doesn't show free disk space, or current directory size, and again, probably becuase that would have been reduntant before October 22.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is an even better solution: [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/) [SourceForge.net]

> Classic Shell is a collection of
>   features that were available in older
>   versions of Windows but are removed
>   from Vista and Windows 7. It has a
>   classic start menu for Windows 7, it
>   adds a toolbar for Windows Explorer
>   and supports a variety of smaller
>   features.