# How to display total filesize of selected files in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 Explorer: how to show total size of all files in current folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/66454/windows-7-explorer-how-to-show-total-size-of-all-files-in-current-folder)

If you have a folder open, if you select a few files, it displays the total filesize at the display bar at the bottom of the folder. However when you select more than 15 files, the total filesize isn't automatically displayed and instead you have to click on "Show more details". How do I get the tab to show the total file size of selected files no matter the number that is selected? I'm pretty sure this wasn't the case in Windows XP!

Comment: Try Explorer++...http://www.explorerplusplus.com/

Answer (score 3):

This has been done to speed up Windows, clicking isn't that hard.

And if it is:

- Select your first item.
- Hold either <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> but do it together with <kbd>ALT</kbd>.
- Select the items you want.
- As <kbd>ALT</kbd> is held, you can simply double click any of your selected items to get the properties.
- Repeat the last two steps and release the keys when you're done selecting.

This allows you to very quickly select a bunch of files that must be constrained to a given size.

Comment: Nice tip. actually i cannot double click any of them, it must be the last selection when doing multiple select for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

actually this feature is intentionally removed from windows 7 because of some performance issues like significant delay time to show the information. so it can not be restored without some registry hacking i think.

you can check out the removed feature list at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_7

so the quick method for keyboard is select the files and press "alt+enter" and it will show the properties dialog with all information. press the "ESC" key to quickly close the properties window.

i think it will help to do thing quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Dave, I guess the only way to know overall file size in that case, is to go to File Properties of the selected items.